# Clock work restart a job after a few minutes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, clockwork

I am using Clock worker gem for back ground process

I have a Configuration table which contains key and value.

My clock.rb file

> ```
> require 'clockwork'
> require './config/boot'
> require './config/environment'
> module Clockwork
>   handler do |job|  
>     puts "Running #{job}" 
>   end
>
>   time = Configuration.find_by(:key=>"time") 
>   if time.present?
>     min = time.value.to_i     
>     every(min.minutes, 'calculate user details') { 
>            User.calculate_time}    
>   end
> end
> ```

When run the worker:  config/clock.rb

This will work fine but when  i am changing time from Configuration,
How worker will work without restart the clock worker file ??

Answer (score 0):

I can think of:

```
module Clockwork
  GET_TIME = -> { Configuration.find_by(key: "time") }
  SETTINGS = { time: GET_TIME.() }
  every(1.minutes, 'reset settings') do 
    Clockwork::SETTINGS[:time] = Clockwork::GET_TIME.()
  end

  handler do |job|  
    puts "Running #{job}" 
  end

  if SETTINGS[:time].present?
    min = SETTINGS[:time].value.to_i     
    every(min.minutes, 'calculate user details') do
      User.calculate_time
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It means `Configuration` caches the config. You should find a way to force it to reload config.